# Логическая ошибка в коде

Tags: delphi

Написал такую процедуру, для того, чтобы отсеивать лишние значения из массива перед прорисовкой, но работает только на первое значение и то его почему-то дублирует и все. Подскажите, где я ошибку делаю?

```
procedure TMainForm.Edit2Change(Sender: TObject);
var
s1,s2,w,d:string;
heh, hah, hoh: real;
h,m,sec,ms:word;
t:TTime;
i:integer;
begin
//пропуск первого числа без сравнения
if (x1<>2184.5) and (edit2.Text<>'2184,5') then //2184,5 – очень плохое число его нам не надо
begin
 if x2=0 then//х2- то число с которым мы будем сравнивать 
    begin
    x1:=strtofloat(edit2.text);
    x3:=strtofloat(edit2.text);//бек ап первого числа для последующего сравнения //х3 служит для контроля данных х2
    x2:=strtofloat(edit2.text); //бек ап первого числа для последующего сравнения
    if (x1<>2184.5) then//2184,5 – очень плохое число его нам не надо
    begin
      //прорисовка
      edit4.Text:=FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now);
      if (edit3.Text<>'') and (edit2.Text<>'2184,5') then
      begin
      listbox3.Items.Add(edit3.Text+'  '+edit2.Text+'  '+FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now));
      ListBox3.TopIndex := -1 + ListBox3.Items.Count;
      s2:= edit4.text;
      Delete(s2, 9, 4);
      t:=StrToTime(s2);
      hah:=strtofloat(edit2.Text );
      hoh:=strtofloat(edit3.Text );
      heh:=t  ;
      Series1.addXY(heh,hah,'',clRed);
      Series2.addXY(heh,hoh,'',clBlue);
      end;
 if x2<>0 then //после того как отработали первую точку\число то по идеи должен срабатывать ниже описанный код 
  begin //но он не работает 
    if abs(x3-x2)<=0.3*x3 then //проверка числа х2 на правильность числа 
      //если правильно то 
      begin
      x1:=strtofloat(edit2.text);
      if abs(x2-x1)<=0.3*x2 then   //если первое число меньше чем второго на х% то делаем дальше 
        begin
        //рисуем
        edit4.Text:=FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now);
        if (edit3.Text<>'') and (edit2.Text<>'2184,5') then begin
        listbox3.Items.Add(edit3.Text+'  '+edit2.Text+'  '+FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now));
        ListBox3.TopIndex := -1 + ListBox3.Items.Count;
        s2:= edit4.text;
        Delete(s2, 9, 4);
        t:=StrToTime(s2);
        hah:=strtofloat(edit2.Text );
        hoh:=strtofloat(edit3.Text );
        heh:=t  ;
        Series1.addXY(heh,hah,'',clRed);
        Series2.addXY(heh,hoh,'',clBlue);
        x3:=x2; переносим значения 
        x2:=x1;
       end;
      end;
    if abs(x3-x2)>=0.3*x3 then  //если разница больше чем надо то
      begin
      x2:= x3-x3*0.2;
      x1:=strtofloat(edit2.text);
      if abs(x2-x1)<=0.3*x2 then   //  если первое число меньше чем второго на х% то делаем дальше      
  begin
            //рисуем
            edit4.Text:=FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now);
            if (edit3.Text<>'') and (edit2.Text<>'2184,5') then begin
              listbox3.Items.Add(edit3.Text+'  '+edit2.Text+'  '+FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now));
              ListBox3.TopIndex := -1 + ListBox3.Items.Count;
              s2:= edit4.text;
              Delete(s2, 9, 4);
              t:=StrToTime(s2);
              hah:=strtofloat(edit2.Text );
              hoh:=strtofloat(edit3.Text );
              heh:=t  ;
              Series1.addXY(heh,hah,'',clRed);
              Series2.addXY(heh,hoh,'',clBlue);
              x3:=x2;
              x2:=x1; 
              end;
          end
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end
    else
    x1:=strtofloat(edit2.text);
  end;
  end; 
end;//ФАЛАТИ!!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас что-то не так с последовательностью сравнений, поэтому одно условие оказалось внутри другого

```
if (x1<>2184.5) and (edit2.Text<>'2184,5') then 
begin
 if x2=0 then
    begin
    ...
    if (x1<>2184.5) then // вот эта проверка не нужна, уже проверили в самом начале процедуры
    begin
      if (edit3.Text<>'') and (edit2.Text<>'2184,5') then
      begin
      ...
      Series2.addXY(heh,hoh,'',clBlue);
      end;
      //вот в этом месте не хватает пары закрывающих 'end;'
      if x2<>0 then //поэтому это условие оказывается внутри if x2=0  
          begin
```

Answer (score 5):

Стиль "пиши всё в OnButtonClick" — не лучший вариант :) Основные направления для рефакторинга:

- разбейте свой код на отдельные небольшие процедуры;
- отделите логику от интерфейса;
- сведите к минимуму использование глобальных переменных.

Не поверите, многие ошибки уйдут сами собой. Удачи.

Comment: @Bosik, совершенно верно, плюсую.

Comment: не спорю но нужно было разобраться конкретно с тем куском )а на будущие учту